# What data notation is this?

Tags: wordpress, types, custom-post-type

I came across this chunk of data while going through a theme's metadata in wordpress. It looks like instead of using several metadata keys for different bits of data, they smooshed it all together in one chunk. This in particular is meta data for an event post type:

```
a:3:{s:8:"dateFrom";s:16:"Mon, 10 Feb 2014";s:6:"dateTo";s:16:"Mon, 10 Feb 2014";s:8:"location";s:87:"Convention Center";}"
```

I mostly just want to extract "dateFrom" so I can display it in a widget.

It looks like for other events the only things that change are the actual values (dates, location). The parts that are `[a-z]:[0-9]*` (which seem to be keys, but they aren't valid JSON keys cause of the colons) are constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is [PHP serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). If you [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it it'll be converted to an array.  So something like (untested):

```
$orig = 'a:3:{s:8:"dateFrom";s:16:"Mon, 10 Feb 2014";s:6:"dateTo";s:16:"Mon, 10 Feb 2014";s:8:"location";s:87:"Convention Center";}"';
$converted = unserialize($orig);
echo $converted['dateFrom'];
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! This did end up working, but then I realized that if I used `get_post_meta` instead of `get_metadata` WP would unserialize it for me. Either way, this is the correct answer, in case this serialization comes up for someone in the future who isn't using WP.

Comment: Cool; glad you got to the bottom of it.  Thanks for accepting.